# format at cell.detailTextLabel.text

Tags: objective-c, format, subtitle

I hava a format problem in cell-subtitle.
I have a string and a number I want to show in subtitle of a cell

String should be left aligned, number right aligned

I tried it in that way:

```
rangeAutor = [rangeAutor stringByPaddingToLength:40-[rangeAutor length] withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];

NSString *subTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@ %1.2f km", rangeAutor, rangeDistance];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = subTitle;
```

result can you see here :-( [format problem](http://myrange.de/support/format.png)

Do you have an idea for me for a solution?

due to the fact I only have 7 reputation, i cant write in comments my answer :-(
So i try to do it here:

```
    static NSString *const kIdentifier = @"SelectRange";
static NSInteger const kDistanceLabelTag = 1;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kIdentifier];
UILabel *distanceLabel;
if (cell) {
    distanceLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kDistanceLabelTag];
} else {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kIdentifier];
    CGRect cellBounds = cell.bounds;
    static CGFloat const kLabelHeight = 20.0f;
    distanceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cellBounds.size.height - kLabelHeight, cellBounds.size.width, kLabelHeight)];
    distanceLabel.tag = kDistanceLabelTag;
    distanceLabel.font = cell.textLabel.font;
    distanceLabel.textColor = cell.textLabel.textColor;
    distanceLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    distanceLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:distanceLabel];
}

UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageNamed:iconName];;
cell.imageView.image = icon;
cell.textLabel.text = rangeName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [@"by " stringByAppendingString:rangeAutor];
distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f km", rangeDistance];
NSLog(@"RangeDistance: %1.2f", rangeDistance);

return cell;
```

to rob mayoff

I changed only small things
but now I cant see rangeDistance in the cell :-(
output of log is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're using a variable-width font.  Each glyph in the font may have a different width.  So you can't just pad the autor out to 40 characters, because “llll” followed by 36 spaces is a different width (on screen) than “MMMM” followed by 36 spaces.

Just give your `cell` another label to hold the distance.  I assume the code in your post is from your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.  You'll need to do something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *const kIdentifier = @"Cell";
    static NSInteger const kDistanceLabelTag = 1;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kIdentifier];
    UILabel *distanceLabel;
    if (cell) {
        distanceLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kDistanceLabelTag];
    } else {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kIdentifier];
        CGRect cellBounds = cell.bounds;
        static CGFloat const kLabelHeight = 20.0f;
        distanceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cellBounds.size.height - kLabelHeight, cellBounds.size.width, kLabelHeight)];
        distanceLabel.tag = kDistanceLabelTag;
        distanceLabel.font = cell.textLabel.font;
        distanceLabel.textColor = cell.textLabel.textColor;
        distanceLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        distanceLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:distanceLabel];
    }

    cell.imageView.image = rangeImage;
    cell.textLabel.text = rangeName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [@"by " stringByAppendingString:rangeAutor];
    distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f km", rangeDistance];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I have solved your problem.  If I have not solved your problem, you should uncheck my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I try to learn objective-c, english and this forum at the same time ;-) the problem ist not solved, now I cant see the rangeDistance ( I edit the question and add my code)

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Works fine. A friend gave me the hint to delet my cell in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a constant value instead of `40-[rangeAutor length]`

Comment: if I change that line to:

    rangeAutor = [rangeAutor stringByPaddingToLength:30 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];

it looks like: 
[link](http://myrange.de/support/format2.png)